# SQLite Query data retrieve from cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 edit boxes in my UI. I want to retrieve data from a table and I want to insert those retrieved data into those edit text boxes how can I insert data into those edit text boxes from cursor?

Comment: very basic question google it ... if any specific issue then let us know... http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your no. of column and its name `cursor.getColumnCount()`  and `cursor.getColumnName(0).` respectively.if your column count is `2` then cursor have two column

```
cursor.moveToFirst();

String columnName1 = cursor.getColumnName(0);
String columnName2 = cursor.getColumnName(1);    

String str1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName1)));
String str2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName2))); 

editext1.seText(str1);   
editext2.seText(str2);
```

after completion of getting data from database close your cursor using `cursor.close();`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Activity.onCreate function

EditText etfirstname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
EditText etlastname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
MyDatabase database = new MyDatabase(this);

Cursor c = database.queryRaw("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id=1"); // query data from database
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    etfirstname.setText(c.getString(0)); // read firstname
    etlastname.setText(c.getString(1)); // read lastname
}

c.close(); // dont forget to close cursor!
```

Comment: If it helped, please dont forget to click on the green check sign next to my answer! :)